# How can I copy a file from a modern machine to a “vintage” Macintosh?

Tags: mac, file-transfer, floppy

My son is working on a school project, the subject is the history of Mac computers.

He’s writing a paper but has to create a visual display too.

I suggested displaying his paper live in MacWrite on an old Mac.

We can get an old Mac easily, but how can we copy a file to it? The best I can come up with is retype it.

We have Windows machines and a Mac Mini, but no other Macs.

Is there a cable that can make a PC or a USB drive look like an external disk drive?  Or a USB floppy drive that can write an old Mac floppy disk format?

Update: Based on information on [this website](http://www.siber-sonic.com/mac/newmillfloppy.html) I think I can use an old SCSI CD-ROM drive with a Mac Plus.

Answer (score 2):

A USB to  DB9 or DB25 adapter, a Null Modem cable, and [Kermit](http://www.columbia.edu/kermit/ck80.html) on both ends.

I'd just re-type it, but I got Cs in school.

Comment: Do old macs have db9 connectors ?  I like this idea.

Comment: At least some do.  
http://groups.google.com/group/vintage-macs/browse_thread/thread/1e3bf15a3783b7e3

Comment: This is actually just a mac modem cable.  But: how do I get kermit on the mac ? I think I still need a floppy.

Comment: You might not need kermit on the old mac.  It may have a terminal program on it.  Did OS 8 or whatever have comms software installed?  It must have.

Answer (score 1):

The most common hardware interface shared by both new and old macs is Ethernet (you may need an additional Ethernet card on some old mac). From this, any IP-based protocol should work, including Appleshare IP. For converting the paper to Macwrite, I suggest plain text.

Comment: I think (very) old macs used LocalTalk at the hardware layer for networking.

Comment: netatalk is the Linux package that speaks appletalk; don't know about support in modern proprietary OS's.

Answer (score 1):

A USB floppy drive would probably be the simplest method. Shove a blank disk in the Plus and let it format it there, then see if it mounts on a newer Mac.

Comment: +1 for formatting it on the older mac. You can also try FAT12/FAT16 from Windows/Linux if the old mac has the "pc exchange" extension loaded.

Answer (score -2):

If the file isn't too large, you can email it to yourself at a web mail address, such as a Yahoo mail or Google mail account. Then you can download it onto the classic Mac.

Comment: It might be hard to believe, but there were times when computers were not connected to the internet...

Comment: @Arjan - Depending on the age, I remember using a beefed up Mac Classic to browse the web in the late 90s. It wasn't fast, it was B&W but it did work. I'd never have used it seriously however.